# ValidateAntiForgeryToken blocking new login

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have an identity server 4 implementation very simple and I'm using the `oidc-client` on my angular APP to carry on all the security management. In my auth service I have the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private manager: UserManager;
    private user: User = null;

    constructor() {
        if (!environment.production) {
            Log.logger = console;
        }
        this.manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
        this.manager.getUser()
                    .then(user => {
                        this.user = user;
                    });
        this.manager.events.addUserSignedOut(() => {
            this.user = null;
            this.signOut();
        });
    }

    signOut(): Promise<void> {
        return this.manager.signoutRedirect()
                           .then(() => {
                               this.manager.clearStaleState();
                           });
    }

    ...more
}

export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
    return {
        authority: environment.authorityUrl,
        client_id: 'myclient',
        redirect_uri: `${environment.baseUrl}/auth-callback`,
        post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.baseUrl,
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        scope: 'openid profile myapi',
        filterProtocolClaims: true,
        loadUserInfo: true,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        revokeAccessTokenOnSignout : true,
        silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.baseUrl}/silent-renew-callback`,
    };
}
```

Everything works like a charm so I can log in/out without any issues, the token renewal works as expected and so far so good. However I decided to implement a "custom" behavior when a user open the application in multiple tabs on the same browser and one of them logs out. Then the event UserSignedOut is triggered and I sign out the rest of the tabs that may be open. The problem I have is that when the user comes back in, the FIRST login attempt is performed correctly, however any subsequent login request from any other tab results in a 400 - BAD REQUEST (removing the Antiforgery token attribute from the login method in my IS4 it then works but I don't want to do so).

If you did refresh the tab then you get logged in therefore to me it seems something wrong with the actual state itself?

I'm not sure if I should invoke any other method in my AuthService prior logging out or whether I should re-implement the ValidateAntiForgeryToken with a custom behavior for this.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you solved that? The behavior is not described enough: did you preload login page after logout on each tab, so the user has to fill and post the form? If so, the AntiForgery fails since it's bound to current Identity, and the Identity changes after the first successful login.

Comment: I did solve that server side. I check if the user is already logged in if so I will bypass the validation of the antiforgerytoken.

Comment: good then! guess you'd implemented something similar to one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295076/antiforgerytoken-expiration-blank-page/)

Comment: Indeed, although rather than being at attribute level I used directly the IAntiforgery at controller level to validate