# AntiForgeryToken Expiration Blank Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, antiforgerytoken

I'm using IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core 2.2. On the Post Login method I have applied the ValidateAntiForgeryToken. Generally after 20 minutes to 2 hours of sitting on the login page and then attempting to login it produces a blank page.

If you look at Postman Console you get a 400 Bad Request message. I then set the Cookie Expiration on the AntiForgery options to 90 days. I was able to allow the page to sit for up to 6 hours and still login. However, after around 8 hours (overnight), I received the blank page again after attempting to login.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login
```

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
});
```

I expect to be able to sit on the login page for 90 days which is the duration of the cookie but that doesn't work. How do I get the cookie for the AntiforgeryToken to last the entire 90 days or whatever time I set it to and not timeout or expire? Is there a way to catch this error and redirect the user back to the login method?

Comment: there is not only the cookie, but also a token inside. and MS has an open [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2421) on setting it's ttl. but as I understand the idea, by default that should live as long as the browser keeps the session... but you can check that with their open code : )

Comment: and regarding changing the behavior: you can override the filter and redirect to the action with the same name, but with HttpGet instead of returning the 400 status

Comment: I was able to control the outcome after validation fails by using this: `await this._antiforgery.IsRequestValidAsync(HttpContext);`. At this moment this is working great for me instead of using the built in attribute.

Comment: glad it works for you, but in general it's better to use some common approach everywhere, and you can finalize the job by wrapping your implementation into a new attribute, then describe it below as the answer for anyone else looking for similar solution...

Comment: Why do you need `AntiForgeryToken`? You are defeating the purpose of AntiForgeryToken here, You are better off without having one in the first place than having such a long duration for that token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update '2021

Since ASP.Net Core 3.0 MS [decided](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22947) to make `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` internal. Now we have to copy-paste [their code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs), to be able to derive. But most likely we don't need to. To just change the resulting behavior all we need is to test the context for the `IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult` and proceed accordantly, as described in this [example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/Filters/RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter.cs).

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace BasicWebSite.Filters
{
    public class RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter : IAlwaysRunResultFilter
    {
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult result)
            {
                context.Result = 
                    new RedirectResult("http://example.com/antiforgery-redirect");
            }
        }

        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        { }
    }
}
```

Then within the controller:

```cs
// POST: /Antiforgery/LoginWithRedirectResultFilter
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[TypeFilter(typeof(RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter))]
public string LoginWithRedirectResultFilter(LoginViewModel model)
{
    return "Ok";
}
```

### The original answer covering .net core 2.2

Yet another implementation using the default one including all prechecks, logging etc. And it's still an `AuthorizationFilter`, so that prevents any further action execution. The only difference is that it triggers `HttpGet` to the same url instead of the default 400 response, a kind of the *Post/Redirect/Get* pattern implementation.

```cs
public class AnotherAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AnotherAntiForgeryTokenAttribute() : base(typeof(AnotherAntiforgeryFilter))
    {
    }
}


public class AnotherAntiforgeryFilter:ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter,
    IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AnotherAntiforgeryFilter(IAntiforgery a, ILoggerFactory l) : base(a, l)
    {
    }

    async Task IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(
        AuthorizationFilterContext ctx)
    {
        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(ctx);

        if (ctx.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
        {
            // the next four rows are optional, just illustrating a way
            // to save some sensitive data such as initial query
            // the form has to support that
            var request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
            var url = request.Path.ToUriComponent();
            if (request.Form?["ReturnUrl"].Count > 0)
                url = $"{url}?ReturnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(request.Form?["ReturnUrl"])}";

            // and the following is the only real customization
            ctx.Result = new LocalRedirectResult(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test this and get back with you later. We've decided to not use the ReturnUrl when Validation fails since it could be at risk. I'm just returning to a view with a message now.

Comment: This worked great. I'm going to go with your solution since it uses the default AntiForgery Validation.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please what is the namespace for ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter. I am using asp.net core 5 and it doesn't seem to find that class. What is the required "Using" statement?

Comment: Things changed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But now, how do I apply this to a razor page? because I need to apply it to login page which is a razor page and it seems (antiforgery) cannot be applied to a razor page the way it is applied to an MVC controller

Comment: According to [this](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification) article, you can use the same attributes with razor pages. So just create your own instead of the `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` they suggested.

Answer (score 4):

This was my final solution. I added a attribute using the IAntifogery dependency injection.

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IAntiforgery _antiForgery { get; }

    public CustomValidationAttribute(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiForgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var isRequestValid = await this._antiForgery.IsRequestValidAsync(context.HttpContext);
        if (!isRequestValid)
        {
            //Add Code here if token is not valid

            return;         
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Add the attribute to your controller methods that also use [HttpPost]

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(CustomValidationAttribute))]
```

Comment: gave you my vote and added an alternative with override. might be a bit simpler, but in general that doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to d_f code https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383473/841898 Instead of page redirect we just add error to ModelState. Then we display in model state summary.

```
public class CustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAntiForgeryTokenAttribute() : base(typeof(AnotherAntiforgeryFilter))
    {
    }
}


public class AnotherAntiforgeryFilter : ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter,
    IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AnotherAntiforgeryFilter(IAntiforgery a, ILoggerFactory l) : base(a, l)
    {
    }

    async Task IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(
        AuthorizationFilterContext ctx)
    {
        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(ctx);

        if (ctx.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult)
        {
            ctx.ModelState.AddModelError("Token", "Validation Token Expired. Please try again");
            ctx.Result = null;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using .netcore 3.1/razor pages and wanted the error put into model state instead of 400 bad request.  Editing from Rodney and Petr J's answers we first globally disabled validation (since autovalidation is on by default) then used a page filter to manually validate.  Not the most efficient but felt more straightforward than trying to catch and revert the [AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs).

Configure Services:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            // Note: This seems to apply globally to all razor areas vs .AddRazorPages()
            
            // First remove default validation which returns 400 Bad Request
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overriding-the-default-order
            options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute() { Order = 1001 });

            // Then add back a page filter, runs on all pages and areas (not tested on anything except razor pages; confirm odata, api, mvc)
            // Option 1 Type activated: instance for each request, DI
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dependency-injection
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(Filters.AntiforgeryValidationModelStateOverridePageFilter));
            
        })
```

Then the custom filter:

```
public class AntiforgeryValidationModelStateOverridePageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter {

    private readonly IAntiforgery _defaultAntiforgery;
    public AntiforgeryValidationModelStateOverridePageFilter(IAntiforgery defaultAntiforgery)
    {
        _defaultAntiforgery = defaultAntiforgery;
    }

    public Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        var isRequestValid = _defaultAntiforgery.IsRequestValidAsync(context.HttpContext).Result;

        if (!isRequestValid)
        {
            //Add Code here if token is not valid
            context.ModelState.AddModelError("", Data.Constants.UserMessages.UserMessageErrorAntiforgery);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context,
                                                  PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // Do post work.
        await next.Invoke();
    }
}
```